# Load local encrypted video file Asset into AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to try read the Data from a encrypted "video" file, decrypt the data and make it run on AVPlayer.

My app can download a video, the video comes encrypted from my API. All I have to do is: decrypt the file with a cypher and then it becomes a valid mp4 file.

Theses steps are covered. I did the process and did write the decrypted data in a file, played it on my machine and passed it with file URL to AVPlayer and it played as well.

However, I do not want have to save the decrypted file. I did a bit of research and came up with AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate. Tried to implement it but without success. The examples I saw was hitting a online URL so I'm not entirely sure if its possible to do it local as I tried.

Any one can help me?

```
        guard var components = URLComponents.init(url: video.url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else { return }
        components.scheme = "encryptedVideo"
        guard let url = components.url else { return }

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: fileDecryptedURL)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        self.avPlayerViewController?.player = player
        self.avPlayerViewController?.player?.play()

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    if let dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest,
        let url = loadingRequest.request.url,
        let contentRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest {

        guard var components = URLComponents.init(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else { return false }
        components.scheme = "file"
        guard let localUrl = components.url else { return false }

        let storageProvider = StorageVideo()
        let dataMaybe = storageProvider.videoData(url: localUrl)

        guard let encryptedData = dataMaybe,
            let decryptedData = try? RNCryptor.decrypt(data: encryptedData,
                                                       withPassword: "omitted") else {
            return false
        }

        contentRequest.contentType = AVFileType.mp4.rawValue
        contentRequest.contentLength = Int64(decryptedData.count)
//            contentRequest.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true

        dataRequest.respond(with: decryptedData)
        loadingRequest.finishLoading()

// Did this to save the file to see if it was ok. I could play the file in my machine 
// If I pass this file url to a asset (above step) it load as well
//            if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
//                let fileDecryptedURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test").appendingPathExtension("mp4")
//                try? decryptedData.write(to: fileDecryptedURL)
//            }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: “However, I do not want have to save the decrypted file” You have to. You can’t play a video file in memory.

Comment: @Rafael Natali do you find any solution?